# Dynamic Camel route generation based on separate OSGi bundles

Tags: jetty, osgi, apache-camel

**Short version:**
Is there a way to have multiple Camel routes, defined in separate OSGi bundles (with supporting processes) shared/merged into a single `CamelContext` such that a single Jetty server could route incoming requests to the separate bundles?

**Background:**
Here is a hypothetical requirement, as the real requirement is confidential...

I am building a modular API backend for a website, the first phase implements simple customer registration, the second phase will implement a forum-like system, the third phase will implement a wiki-like system.  As each system completes development, I need to be able to add the new system to the API backend without modifying the other components or (ideally) taking the system offline.

In trying to implement something like this, I thought of having each API system in it's own OSGi bundle, and using Camel and Jetty to field the incoming API requests, each system would register a path under the jetty base URL and receive messages destined for it from the Camel routing mechanism.  I've run into trouble with this design because if I configure a route in each bundle, they operate in separate `CamelContext`s, so the first bundle runs, but the second tries to spawn another Jetty server on the same port, and fails.

I then though to make an OSGi service that would take a `RouteBuilder` and add it to the existing "master" `CamelContext` (`suspend`, `addRoutes`, `resume`).  This doesn't work because the master `CamelContext` doesn't see the services/processes in the separate API bundles. It also doesn't allow for XML-based configuration.

I'm open to different ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the servlet component instead of the jetty component. It can register a servlet with the OSGi HTTPService. Then all servlet routes use this servlet and can register own subpaths. This works across bundles and should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked for what I need, thanks!  Claus' version works as well, but I can only mark one answer "right"...bummer

Answer (score 0):

Ah yeah a bit tricky I guess.

In your client bundles I would assume you can use the OSGi service registry to export services for your RouteBuilder classes, which has the routes.

For example using a blueprint xml file, you can export those route builder as OSGi services. Then in the bundle with the Camel context, you can reference these services, which then you can refer to from CamelContext

```
<!-- osgi references goes here -->

<camelContext ...>
  <routeBulderRef ref="myClientRoute"/>
  <routeBulderRef ref="myOtherClientRoute"/>
   ...
</camelContext>
```

If you want to use XML DSL for your client routes, then that may be a bit more tricky. You can have a `<routeContext id="myClientRoute">` in blueprint XML files. Though how to export the  as an OSGi service may be tricky.

Maybe we could some way have `<routeContext>` register themselves as OSGi services. We do this for `<camelContext`>.

Comment: If I understand this example correctly, I would have to have the camelContext "know" about all the routeBuilders at launch time.  That doesn't allow for new routes to be added/removed at runtime, which I guess is what I'm trying to do, with the new routes defined in separate bundles.

Comment: One idea would be to use a light-weight messaging bus, like ZeroMQ, and have all jetty requests pushed onto the bus to be picked up by the bundles, but, I'd need a way for Jetty to wait for the response, if that's possible.

Comment: Ah yeah the Jetty server is reused if using same port. I posted a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yeah in OSGi the Jetty server is shared between Camel bundles if you use the same port number. This allows you to install new Camel routes in separate bundles, and let them each have their own lifecycle, so you can install/uninstall the bundles as you wish.

And yes as Christian also says you can use camel-servlet instead. Then it uses the OSGi HTTP service. Which for Apache ServiceMix / Karaf is using Jetty as the servlet container implementation. You can configure its jetty configuration in configuration files in the etc directory of ServiceMix/Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

Use same port number will do.

This raises another question:

If the jetty is shared, how can we control min/max threads.

example:

In routeA.xml:

```
<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9191/proxy/serviceA/?maxThread=20">
...
```

In routeB.xml:

```
<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9191/proxy/serviceB/?maxThread=50">
...
```

Which configuration will be in effect?